# Manually add a floorplan to Google Maps with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google maps app that I need to be able to upload different floorplans to. So far I am adding the floorplan image to the map using a ground overlay object like this:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(floorplan.get_swlat(), floorplan.get_swlng()),
new LatLng(floorplan.get_nelat(), floorplan.get_nelng()));

GroundOverlayOptions overlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(floorplan.get_floorplanimage())).positionFromBounds(bounds);

mMap.addGroundOverlay(overlayOptions);
```

This adds the floorplan to the map, but the problem is that it is only north-south facing, so it won't work for buildings that don't perfectly sit like that. So I was wondering if there was a way to go in and manually place it (and use fingers to rotate and scale the image) where I need it to be. Anyone know where to even begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time but I finally figured something out. Instead of adding the overlay using the two corners I use the center lat/lon and the width and height. I add the overlay as follows.

```
mOverlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(floorplan.get_floorplanimage()))
            .position(new LatLng(floorplan.get_clat(), floorplan.get_clng()), (float) floorplan.get_width(), (float) floorplan.get_height())
            .bearing((float) floorplan.get_bearing())
            .transparency(mOpacity);
mOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(mOverlayOptions);
```

So you have to give the floorplan initial values to begin.Then I added two markers, one located at the center of the overlay (same lat/lon) and another one located along the center of the right edge of the overlay (mSizeMarker). Make sure they're draggable. I had to do some math to figure out where to place the one on the right edge.

```
mCenterMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(floorplan.get_clat(), floorplan.get_clng())));

Double new_longitude = floorplan.get_clng() + (floorplan.get_width() / 2 / (6371000)) * (180 / 3.14159265) / Math.cos(floorplan.get_clat() * 3.14159265/180);
mSizeMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(floorplan.get_clat(), new_longitude)));

mCenterMarker.setDraggable(true);
mSizeMarker.setDraggable(true);
```

All that's left is to add an OnMarkerDragListener:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.equals(mCenterMarker)) {
                mOverlay.remove();
                mOverlayOptions.position(marker.getPosition(), mOverlay.getWidth(), mOverlay.getHeight());
                mOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(mOverlayOptions);
                mSizeMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude + (mOverlay.getWidth() / 2 / (6371000)) * (180 / 3.14159265) / Math.cos(marker.getPosition().latitude * 3.14159265/180)));
            }
            if (marker.equals(mSizeMarker)) {
                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(mCenterMarker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude));
                double newWidth = ((marker.getPosition().longitude - mCenterMarker.getPosition().longitude) / ((180 / 3.14159265) / Math.cos(mCenterMarker.getPosition().latitude * 3.14159265/180))) * 6371000 * 2;
                mOverlay.remove();
                mOverlayOptions.position(mCenterMarker.getPosition(), (float) newWidth);
                mOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(mOverlayOptions);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.equals(mSizeMarker)) {
                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(mCenterMarker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude));
            }
        }
    });
```

Use the middle marker to drag where you want the floorplan to be located, and the one on the right to change the width (the height will automatically update correspondingly).

Then when the image is positioned correctly, just have a save button somewhere that updates where the floorplan is stored with the position, width, and height of mOverlay. It would be possible to add another marker to manually adjust the bearing, but that's more math than I need to do right now. I'll just keep adjusting it when I set it originally. Hope this helps anyone else who comes along this problem, I know this solution is working great for me so far.